# Question about minimal sufficient statistic and complete sufficient statistic

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X$ is a random sample of size $n$ from a parametric family of distributions indexed by $\theta$.  If $T(X)$ is complete sufficient for $\theta$ and $S(X)$ is minimal sufficient for $\theta$, show that $T(X)$ and $S(X)$ are equivalent.

I am a bit confused about this problem. Can a minimal sufficient statistic be incomplete? Any hint or help is welcome.

Comment: The typical example of an incomplete minimal sufficient statistic is  $X \sim N(\mu,\mu^2)$ where $\left(\sum x_i,\sum x_i^2\right)$ is minimum sufficient but not complete since $2\left(\sum x_i^2\right) - (n+1)\left(\sum x_i\right)^2$ has expectation $0$.  That does not help with your proof; instead note that a minimal sufficient statistic is a function of any sufficient statistic.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/435938/119261